# Как решить проблему проверки? (vk_api, Bot LongPoll)

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

У меня есть бот в ВК. Уже на протяжении  недели никак не могу доделать одну  функцию боту -проверку времени.

```
def CaptureGo(chat_id):
    if now.tm_hour == 0 and now.tm_min == 0:
        write_msg(chat_id, 'сообщение')
```

Рекомендовали использовать потоки, но не помогает.

Сама проблема заключается в том, что проверка-то проходит в функции, но срабатывание происходит только тогда, когда я что-то напишу в чат

Это должно не так работать, помогите мне исправить ошибку

Comment: Эта функция находится у Вас в `listen()` цикле, я прав? В таком случае она выполняется только когда приходит очередное событие. Вам правильно рекомендовали потоки, необходимо вынести функцию за цикл. Я как раз хотел это реализовать. Если у меня получится, отвечу Вам подробнее.

Comment: @nomnoms12, да-да, вы правы. Приятно снова вас видеть =)

Comment: @gil9red, Простите, вы были правы. Спасибо вам за помощь!

Comment: @nomnoms12, Так моя проблема ещё не решена. Я поблагодарил человека, за то что дал такую подсказку. А вот реализовать правильно, я не её не могу. Мне просто кажется, что я как будто, не ищу ответ на свой вопрос, а ищу людей, которые, чтобы просто помогли и всё. Мои навыки программирование ниже среднего, но не ниже низкого. Реализовать всё красиво я так не могу. Надеюсь вы меня поняли. Как получиться реализовать, прошу, объясните, чтобы возможно в дальнейшем, не было больше таких вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD:**

Я пересмотрел своё мнение и код ниже довольно плох, не используйте его. Рекомендую обратить внимание на модуль `shedule`.

---

Я решил использовать `threading.Timer`

Этот класс создаёт отдельный поток (что не мешает работе программы) и через определённый промежуток времени запускает некоторую функцию.

Но в нашем случае этого недостаточно. Наша программа должна:

1. Вычислить промежуток времени до первого срабатывания (в примере это 12:00)
2. Запустить функцию через найденный промежуток времени
3. После завершения работы функции запустить новый таймер с новым интервалом.

Для этих целей я создал класс-обёртку `CustomTimer`. Он дополняет стандартный `Timer` нашим функционалом:

***UPD:***

```py
from vk_api import VkApi
from threading import Timer
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from random import randint


def send_msg(vk, chat_id, message):
    random_id = randint(1, 2147483647)

    vk.messages.send(
        random_id=random_id,
        chat_id=chat_id,
        message=message
    )


def get_delta(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0):
    now = datetime.now()
    run_at = now.replace(hour=hour, minute=minute, second=second, microsecond=microsecond)
    if run_at < now:
        run_at += timedelta(days=1)

    return (run_at - now).total_seconds()


class CustomTimer:
    def __init__(self, *args, delta=0.0, function=send_msg, interval=86400.0, **kwargs):
        self.delta = delta
        self.interval = interval
        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

        self.timer = None

    def callback(self):
        self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        self.normal_start()

    def normal_start(self):
        self.timer = Timer(self.interval, self.callback)
        self.timer.start()

    def start(self):
        self.timer = Timer(self.delta, self.callback)
        self.timer.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    vkSession = VkApi(token=[Ваш токен])
    vk = vkSession.get_api()

    delta = get_delta(21, 51)
    t = CustomTimer(vk, [id Вашей беседы], 'Раз в 5 секунд', delta=delta, interval=5)
    t.start()

    delta = get_delta(21, 51)
    t = CustomTimer(vk, [id Вашей беседы], 'Раз в 3 секунды', delta=delta, interval=3)
    t.start()

    delta = get_delta(21, 51)
    t = CustomTimer(vk, [id Вашей беседы], 'Раз в 10 секунд', delta=delta, interval=10)
    t.start()
```

Чтобы воспользоваться классом нужно:

1. Передать все аргументы, которые ждёт потенциальная функция (в примере это `send_msg`). Я передаю объект для доступа к api, id беседы и нужное сообщение.
2. Указать время в секундах до первого запуска. Для удобства я создал функцию `get_delta`. Параметры этой функции определены по-умолчанию нулем, так что указывать время довольно удобно (в примере я запускаю все потоки в 21:51).
3. Указать интервал. Это тот промежуток времени, через который будет вызываться функция. Например, если вы хотите запускать её раз в день, то укажите 86400 и т. д.
4. Указать функцию для запуска.

Многие параметрам я дал значение по умолчанию (например, функции), так как в большинстве случаев Вы будете использовать одни и те же значения.

Comment: Вы - гений. Я бы просто до такого бы не догадался. А Вы, раз-раз, и всё! Теперь у меня есть пару вопросов. Вот где уже в объекте Thread, ["id Вашего чата"], можно ли использовать просто `chat_id`, а не вписывать какое-то число? В функцией `def start()`, можно ли делать множество проверок, меняя переменную, допустим `run_at1..run_at2....`, чтобы было несколько проверок времени. Вместо сообщения `'Полдень'` указывать переменную с сообщением, то есть реализовать отправку сообщения в `def start()`.

Comment: @hoojpop Насчёт передачи аргументов, конечно, Вы можете передать переменную. В конце концов, она заменится на значение. Изменить интервал и начальное значение тоже можно. Для этого нужно изменить `__init__` и создать несколько экземпляров таймера по Вашим условиям. Опишите все условия, и я постараюсь Вам помочь.

Comment: Ну смотри, мне нужно, чтобы проверка начиналась с 1:00, и была каждые два часа, то есть 1:00 .. 3:00 и т.д. И чтобы в каждое время был разный текст. Как это сделать?

Comment: Давайте продолжим обсуждение в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94925/discussion-on-answer-by-nomnoms12-----vk-api-bot-lon)

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Просто, огромное спасибо! Больше ни как не сказать.